# How to find direct children of element in lxml

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I found an object with specific class:

```py
THREAD = TREE.find_class('thread')[0]
```

Now I want to get all `<p>` elements that are its direct children.

I tried:

```py
THREAD.findall("p")

THREAD.xpath("//div[@class='thread']/p")
```

But all of those returns all `<p>` elements inside this `<div>`, no matter if that `<div>` is their closest parent or not.

How can I make it work?

**Edit:**

Sample html:

```
<div class='thread'>
   <p> <!-- 1 -->
      <!-- Can be some others <p> objects inside, which should not be counted -->
   </p> 
   <p><!-- 2 --></p>
</div>
<div class='thread'>
   <p>[...]</p>
   <p>[...]</p>
</div>
```

script should find two objects `<p>`, which are children of `THREAD`. I should receive list of two objects, marked as "1" and "2" in comments in sample HTML.

**Edit 2:**

Yet another clarification, since people get confused:

`THREAD` is some object stored in variable, can be any html element. I want to find `<p>` objects that are direct children of `THREAD`. Those `<p>`'s can not be outside `THREAD` or inside any element that's also inside `THREAD`.

Comment: Can you share HTML sample for the same along with current and desired output?

Comment: @Andersson: sample HTML added

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but it seem that your problem is in HTML itself: note that [there are couple Tag omission cases applicable for `p` nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p), so closing tags of paragraphs

```
<div class='thread'>
    <p>first
        <p>second</p>
    </p>
</div>
```

simply ignored by parser and both nodes identified as siblings, but not parent and child, e.g.

```
<div class='thread'>
    <p>first
    <p>second
</div>
```

So XPath `//div[@class="thread"]/p` will return you both paragraphs

You can simply replace `p` tags with `div` tags and you'll see different behaviour:

```
<div class='thread'>
    <div>first
        <div>second</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here `//div[@class="thread"]/div` will return first node only

Please correct me if my assumption is incorrect

Comment: yeah, I came to the same conclusion. You are right, that caused a problem. I'm not sure which answer should be marked as best, since your post solved actual problem, but @zx485's solved problem describied in question xD

Comment: Good observation.  The browser's sibling-`p` interpretation of your example follows from HTML allowing `p` end tags to be omitted (SGML end-tag omission anachronism) and not expecting `p` elements to be nested (a valid rule).

Answer (score 1):

Try this XPath expression:

```
//p[parent::div[@class='thread']]
```

Or in a complete Python expression:

```py
THREAD.xpath("//p[parent::div[@class='thread']]")
```

The other (inverse) approach is this XPath expression:

```
div[@class='thread']/child::p"
```

which uses the direct `child::` axis and only selects the direct child nodes.

Summary:
Which one of both expressions is faster depends on the XPath compiler. `child::` is the default axis and is used if no other axis is given.

---

FYI: XPath counting starts at **1** and **not 0**.
So concerning your XML example, the following expression

```
count(//div[@class='thread'][1]/child::p)
```

does result in a value of 2 - the result of counting `<p> <!-- 1 -->` + `<p><!-- 2 --></p>`.

Comment: seems like it's some kind of workaround... Is in xpath some way to tell that elements I look for have to be children of object I call `xpath` function on?

Comment: the problem here is: if I added another `<div class='thread'>` with `<p>` objects inside to my html, than it wouldn't work properly, because it would find all `<p>`s that have parent `<div class='thread'>`, not the ones that are in this specific `<div>`

Comment: @Piotrek: This XPath expression does just that: it selects all `p`s which are a child of a certain parent. I'll just add the reverse approach :-)

Comment: I tested both approaches with a test file and both yield the same result.

Comment: @Piotrek: This would be a lot easier if you edited the **desired result** in your question.

Comment: check out the question now, added more details

Answer (score 0):

You can try **PARENT.getchildren()**

```
>>> root = etree.fromstring(xml)
>>> root.xpath("//div[@class='thread']")[0].getchildren()
[<Element p at 0x10b3110e0>, <Element p at 0x10b311ea8>]
```