# XPath to display inner HTML contents

Tags: xpath, lxml

Below is a representation of some malformed HTML that I get

```
<body><article >
    <p><div  ><img src="xyz"><noscript><img src="xyz" /></noscript><p class="caption">ABC</p></div>EFG. </p>
    <p>HIJ.</p>
    <p>KLM</p>
    <p>NOP</p>
</article></body>
```

How do I retrieve every thing within the first 'p' tag i.e. the entire

```
<div  ><img src="xyz"><noscript><img src="xyz" /></noscript><p class="caption">ABC</p></div>EFG.
```

I have tried

```
output = tree.xpath("//article/p")
```

When I try to loop through the child nodes (len(output[0])), it gives me a count of 0 meaning it has no child nodes.

When I do

```
print output[0].text
```

I get None. If I do

```
lxml.etree.tostring(output[0])
```

I get

```
</p>
```

Comment: You cannot get correct innerHTML from provided malformed HTML code sample. You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48548296/how-to-find-direct-children-of-element-in-lxml/48550674#48550674) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Try this XPath:

```
/body/article/p[1]
```

But this doesn't take care of the *malformed* issue.

Comment: Tried it but it gives me """<p/>"""

Answer (score 0):

Try using `soupparser` instead, it should parse broken html.

```
from lxml.html import soupparser

with open(path, 'r') as f:
    tree = soupparser.parse(f)

    output = tree.findall('//article/p')

    print(output[0].xpath('.//text()'))
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It got me a bit closer to what I wanted. This doesn't give me the tags inside but it gives me all the text which is something.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you can get all the content of first p tag.This answer is referred to the previous answer.

```
from lxml.html import soupparser, tostring

with open(your_file_path, 'rb') as f:
    tree = soupparser.parse(f)
output = tree.findall('//article/p')
print(tostring(output[0]).decode('utf-8'))
```